# How much do I gain if a dollar is given or taken away repeatedly (so long as I have *some* money)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Say I receive or lose $\Delta N$ dollars with equal probability, but if I have zero dollars, I can't lose any (i.e. I can only gain when I have no dollars), then how do I describe statistically the increase in the amount of money I have? I am guessing the money would have to increase with time. Does this problem have a name and can it be generalized to the case when probabilities are not equal?
(I adapted this from a physics problem)

Comment: The term "random walk" describes the situation without the boundary condition - it might be a good term to poke around with in case it's not familiar to you. I couldn't find what this particular constraint is called - but, even if it's not been researched before, a lot of results about random walks are definitely possible to generalize to the situation you describe.

Comment: Your expected money increases over time, yes, but you will also go broke infinitely often (simple random walk is recurrent).  It's similar to reflecting random walk.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be studied using discrete-time Markov chains/processes.

The problem can be generalized by considerating different amounts of money with different probabilities, for example: say you start with m dollars, and every hour you either receive 1 dollar, 3 dollars or lose 2 dollars with probabilities 1/4, 1/4 and 1/2 respectively; if you have 1 dollar and you lose 2, you only get to 0; if you have 0 dollars then you can only gain 1 or 3 with probabilities 1/2 and 1/2.
If you model this using a Markov chain you can calculate, for example, the probability that you will have 100 dollars after 12 hours.

Note that the probability of having certain amount of money after n hours only depends on the amount of money you had after n-1 hours. This is what characterizes Markov  processes. You can find more information about Markov processes in any introductory book to stochastic processes.